# For every prime of the form 6x-1 are there comparable number of primes of the form 6x+1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

All primes except $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6x-1$ and $6x+1$. For every prime of the form $6x-1$ are there comparable number of primes of the form $6x+1$ in the first $10000$ primes or is there an excess of one form over the other?
Thanks

Comment: See the answer to a similar question that I have posted at http://mathoverflow.net/q/165887/27456.

Comment: Do you mean something like "among the first $N$ primes, are there comparable numbers of primes of the forms $6x-1$ and $6x+1$"?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, but if we define $f(n)$ as the percentage of primes less than $n$ that are of the form $6n-1$, then $f(n)\to \frac{1}{2}$ as $n\to\infty$. It's not clear what you mean by "for each prime of the form $6x-1$..." That's a bit badly formed.

Comment: Thanks all. apologize for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Among the first 10000 primes, there are $4988$ of the form $6k + 1$ and $5010$ of the form $6k-1$. Got these numbers using dumb computer search.

Answer (score 0):

Going beyond $10000$ (which, as Dan Shved pointed out, you could simply count), the following fact illustrates that the primes are "equally" spread between $6n-1$ and $6n+1$ forms. Define 
$\chi(p)=-1$ if $p\equiv 1\bmod 3$ and $\chi(p)=1$ if $p\equiv -1 \bmod 3$. Then the series
$$
\sum_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{\chi(p)}{p} \tag1
$$
converges. Since the series $\sum_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p}$ diverges, the finiteness of (1) demonstrates that the positive contribution of the primes of the form $6n-1$ is evenly matched by the negative contributions of the primes of the form $6n+1$.

For more, see  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91038/) by Bruno Joyal.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer